# Java. Как использовать переменную, объявленную внутри блока if-else, вне самого блока?

Tags: java, переменные

Вот пример, в конце для вычисления x нужна переменная z2, объявленная внутри if-else. IDEA подсвечивает ее красным, что делать?

```
public class laba2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("add b");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String sb = reader.readLine();
        int b = Integer.parseInt(sb);
        if (b>10) {
            System.out.println("No solutions");
        }
        else {
            if (b == 10) {
                .double z2 = Math.tan(b);
            }
            else {
                double z2 = 1;
            }
        }
        double z1 = (90-b*b)/(Math.sqrt(3*b*b+1));
        double x = (z1*z1*z1-1)/(z2*z2+1);
        double y = 1/Math.tan(x)-Math.sqrt(1+x*x);
        System.out.println("z1 " +z1+ " z2 " + " x " +x+ " y " +y+ " b " +b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Объявите её за пределами блока, а в блоке сделайте присвоение значения.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае область видимости переменной - фигурные скобки блока if. Объявите переменную z2 в начале метода, что бы она была доступна из любого места в методе.